# ssh-copy-id user@host prompts for password but it isn't being accepted

Tags: openssh

After creating an RSA key with the command `ssh-keygen`, I'm trying to install it with `ssh-copy-id user@host` but it prompts me for `user@host` password. So I enter the password used to login on my PC but it does not work, it returns "permission denied". I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Since the neccessary files are copied across the network, you need to have the password for the _remote_ host, which may or may not be the same you use locally.

Comment: Can you ssh into that remote system using the exact same username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know username and password of a remote machine. Try the following procedure:

> 1. ssh-keygen -t rsa

where, 't' is the type of key to be generated. It prompts for the directory_path, enter your's or press enter to use default.

> 2. ssh-copy-id -i ~/path_you_specified/id_rsa.pub user@remote_ip_address

where 'i' is the identity file.

> 3. ssh user@remote_ip_address

Now, you should be able to login into a remote server without password.